# How to approximate measurement uncertainty?

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, mean, uncertainty

At the moment I use standard deviation of the mean to estimate uncertainty:

$$\sigma_\textrm{mean}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$$

where $N$ is in hundreds and mean is a time series (monthly) mean. I
present it then like this:

$$O_n\geq \frac{-\log_{10} 0.05}{b}$$

for each element (month) in the (annual) time series.

Is this valid? Is this appropriate for time series?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question depends a lot on how your measurement uncertainty arises. If it is due to to uncorrelated normally distributed fluctuations in your measurement your measurement outcomes will also be normally distributed.

If this assumption is valid can be hard to prove, but plotting histograms of outcomes of independent measurement should give you a feeling for the shape (and size) of the uncertainty.

Since the normal distribution works on a unlimited range of values, typical cases where measurements are not normally distributed are counting experiments where the number to be measured is small (e.g. less than 20) and/or fluctuations are large, or when the measured quantity is defined to be in a range, e.g. a fraction. One might still use normal approximation in a certain range though.

Comment: I've updated the question with the information on kind of time series/mean I'm talking about.

Comment: @Silent: We would still need to guess what your problem really is. What is N? Number of sunflares in hundreds or the voltage you measure on some battery? It would suggest you plot your monthly means in a histogram. Fit this with a Gaussian an see if it fits and if you can justify a Gaussian fit from your model.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the above works for uncertainty of the mean is because of the central limit theorem.

As long as the central limit theorem holds for your application, so will the above.